# Notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement for an application, when it has multiple notifications and when the user clicks one of those, the rest of the notifications of the same app should still be visible in the notification centre. Normally what happens is those other notifications also get cleared. Is there a way that I can bypass this scenario?

Update - Is there a way that we can access received push notifications in the notification center?

Comment: are you talking about Push notifications, or Local notifications?

Comment: about push notifications..

Comment: my proposal would be like this: __1.__ App State: minimised. There are 3 notifications. __2.__ User launches app from any of them, or just opens the app. __3.__ App figures if it was launched from notification, or not (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) __4.__ App fetches all unread notifications from the backend (excluding one if app was launched from notification) __5.__ After fetching all notifications: when user minimises the App: create UILocalNotification instances with data fetched from backend

Comment: You should be able to look into your push notification before it is actually shown? In that case you can just look for the notifications u actually want to react to (by means of settings etc). http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 has a good tutorial on push notifications in general.

Comment: Is there any other way we can do this instead of populating local notifications for the unread ones? Even if I implement that is there a way we can read the unread push notifications which we already received? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done by iOS. Programmers have no control over it.

You can get the notification if the user click on the item in notification center and application is opening from it. Following is the code for it

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
   //your notification will be in the dictionary if application is opening from notification center
   return YES;
}
```